# Include file in a function and access their variables in parent program

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
function something() {
   require_once("something.php");
}
```

something.php has some variables

```
<?php 
$something = "something";
?>
```

I want to be able to access the `$something` from the main program. How can I do this?

Eg:

```
something();
echo $something;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't include it inside a function ?! Please show us your **full** and **real** function how you include your files

Comment: This is a part of a bigger program ;)

Comment: ^ That's why I wanted to see the function so we can show you how you can do this outside of the function and get access to the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function something() {
    require('something.php');
    foreach (get_defined_vars() as $varName => $varValue) {
        if (!in_array($varName, ['_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_FILES', '_SERVER'])) {
            global $$varName;
            $$varName = $varValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not normal to use such technique!

See to modern PHP frameworks like [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/).
Totally, if you have an **require** or **include** instruction in your regular files, you probably have a problems in project architecture.

Comment: 1. I think you wanted this: `get_defined_vars()` 2. Very bad practice to use ALL variables in global scope inside a function! You break the logic/existence why functions exists!

Comment: Yep, `get_defined_vars()`. I write it without check =).

Comment: Still with this you completely break the logic behind a function! And OP may run into a few problems with using this and the code will get very hard to read and understand where variables comes from!

Comment: Rizier123, i agree with you. But it is only my answer to authors question.

Comment: Well you may wanted to include this in your answer if you agree with me, before you posted the answer. Because OP accept your answer, so it seems like he uses now your method. And if OP's next question is about weird variable values I know where I will link him

Comment: Rizer123, ok. I'd add comment that this is not normal to use such technique.